# Expected value of PDF with two variables

Tags: probability, integration

$A$ and $B$ have the joint PDF

$$f_{A,B}(a,b)={1\over \sqrt{3}\pi}\exp\left[-{2\over 3}(a^2 - ab + b^2)\right]$$

Find $E[A],E[B],\mathrm{Var}[A],\mathrm{Var}[B]$.

This is the problem i want to solve. 
Here is what i know: 
$$E[f(A,B)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(a,b)f_{A,B}(a,b)da,dy$$
so what is the method that find $E[A]$ ?

Comment: Try $f(a,b)=a$.

Comment: @StefanHansen what do you mean? you meaning $E[f_{A,B}(a,b)]=E[A]$ ?

Comment: No. Try your formula for $E[f(A,B)]$ with the specific $f$ given by $f(a,b)=a$.

Comment: i dont get it :(

Comment: "Here is what i know:" - It seems like you _don't_ know the  formula you displayed. Perhaps you should take a look at some examples in your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Putting  $f(a,b)=a$ we have

$$
\mathbb{E}(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}a f_{A,B}(a,b)\,da\,db
$$

$$
\mathbb{E}(A^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}a^2 f_{A,B}(a,b)\,da\,db
$$

$$
\mathrm{Var}(A)=\mathbb{E}(A^2)-(\mathbb{E}(A))^2
$$

The same for $B$.